# Is there a way to find the IMAP mailbox that contains all mail, regardless of provider?

Tags: email, imap, email-client

I was wondering if there exists a way or maybe a convention to figure out what the IMAP mailbox is for each e-mail provider that contains all (non-spam) e-mail.

For GMail it's `[Gmail]/All Mail`, but it's obviously different for other services.

Does one have to inspect the mailboxes of each service or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server supports [RFC 6154](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154), "IMAP LIST Extension for Special-Use Mailboxes", then the results of the `LIST` command should contain the attribute `\All` for the mailbox that contains all mail:

```
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \All) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
```

Gmail supports this; not sure which other providers do.

Comment: Amazing. I wonder why I keep googling when SE experts provide the perfect answer within 30 seconds. Many thanks!

Comment: Note, All Mail is not standard, and it won't be found on most services.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no way which works on *all* servers. As the other answer suggests, RFC6154's `\All` is what you are looking for, but servers are not required to implement such a mailbox.

Comment: Then a follow-up question, if you'll allow: would all servers have an "INBOX" folder? (or would some give it a different name?) (I know the mailbox marked "All" isn't the same as the INBOX one, but it's the second best alternative for servers who don't support the "All" attribute)

Comment: INBOX is the only folder that is required to exist, and should be the users primary mailbox. It may however be capitalized differently, but servers should treat it case insensitively.

Comment: I don't see a requirement for existence of INBOX in RFC3501.